# Disabling Tabbed Browsing Based On Website

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

A client is reporting a problem using our Web-Based application. It seems that their users are opening Multiple tabs while using the site. It leads to a problem where they lose track of what tab they are on and sometimes enter invalid data or view data in the wrong context believing that they are on a different tab.

Though I have proposed different solutions for them they only want to consider one solution: disabling tabbed browsing when their users are on our site, and enabling it again when they are not.

Is such a thing possible? All the users are using Windows (XP, I believe, although possibly W7) and Internet Explorer 7+.

I wasn't sure if there is a Windows Scripting solution that can accomplish this, or maybe an ActiveX control that has this capability.

**EDIT: 2012/08/13** One feature I am now considering is a custom Internet Explorer application. Something similar to what the poster is talking about here:

http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/ie8-virtual-layer-custom-ie-settings

and here

http://www.vandyke.com/support/tips/ieobject.html

This is new ground to me so if someone with experience here has any ideas I would love to hear it.

Comment: You do anything to alter the operation of my software on my machine, I would not be happy with you.  Why not just make your links quit opening new tabs?

Comment: Yes, obviously this is not the right approach to the problem. It is a case of user error and the solution should reflect that (user training, e.g.). However, humans will be humans, and I guess a stern lecture failed so the customer is seeking more dramatic measures for their user base. My links do not open new tabs, but users can obv choose to open a link in a new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do this.  IE will only allow the user to make choices around how tabs work, not the website.  It does not have a feature for controlling this on a per-site basis.

If modifying the application to behave differently when it detects this happening is off the table, your client (the people) can just disable tabbed browsing completely using administrative tools.

Comment: Another option is to have the Web site detect that there are multiple sessions from the same client and automatically shut down the old session. (I.e., have the old page change their content to "This session has been closed because a new session was opened in another tab or window.")